# Execute two function at the same time with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the following problem: I have two components in React. The first component executes a function that runs a timer. The timer uses the method setInterval() to decrease the seconds on each call until cero. When the timer reaches 0 I call clearInterval() and this function stops. During the period of time in which the timer is running, I have a second component that has a button. That button has an onClick property that calls a function. This function sends a request to my node.js server. Bare in mind that while the button is being click and its function is called, the timer is constantly calling the function that decreases the seconds.

So I find that when the button in the second component fires its function, there is no request reaching the server. I have tested that the connection between client and server and the routes work using Postman. I have also tested that my onClIck method actually fires the function by displaying an alert().

So, that let me to believe that I am dealing with something related to the single thread in JS. If someone with more expertise and knowledge could guide me on this matter I would appreciated a lot. This is my code:

```
//component that starts timer

const startTimer = (sitNumber) => {
  const id = setInterval(async () => {
    updateSec = updateSec - 1;

    console.log("updateSec", updateSec);
    console.log("minutes", time.m);

    if (updateSec === 0) {
      updateMin = updateMin - 1;
      updateSec = 60;
    }

    if (time.m <= 0 || updateMin <= 0) {
      clearInterval(id);
      const response = await fetch(
        "http://localhost:3005/dashboard/unblocksit",
        {
          method: "PUT",
          headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            flightName: flight.flightName,
            sit: sitNumber,
          }),
        }
      );
      const parseResponse = await response.json();
      setCount2(count + 1);
      setShowCheckOut(false);
      setTime({ s: 60, m: 4 });
      console.log("this is the unblock response", parseResponse);
    }
    return setTime({ s: updateSec, m: updateMin });
  }, 1000);
};
```

Keep in mind that while the above function is running every second for 4 minutes, the below function is fired with a click

```
//component that sends request to server

const buyTicket = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // alert('button clicked') //it actually dsiplays the alert
  try {
    //In postman this url works properly
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3005/dashboard/buyticket", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        flight: flight.flightName,
        sit: sit.sitNumber,
        price: sit.price,
        origin: flight.origin,
        destination: flight.destination,
        passenger,
      }),
    });
    const parseResponse = response.json();
    console.log(parseResponse);
    setCount3(count3 + 1);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

return (
  <div>
    <div className="timer">
      <span>{time.m <= 0 ? time.m : "0" + time.m}</span>
      <span>{time.s <= 0 ? time.s : "0" + time.s}</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <form>
        <label>Passenger full name</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={passenger}
          onChange={(e) => setPassenger(e.target.value)}
        />

        <button onClick={buyTicket}>Purchase</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Finally, this is the server side:

```
buyTicket: async (req, res) => {
  console.log("hello from buyticket controller"); //I dont even get this console.log
  const flight = req.body.flightName;
  const sit = req.body.sitNumber;
  const price = req.body.price;
  const origin = req.body.origin;
  const detination = req.body.destination;
  const passenger = req.body.passenger;

  const sitUnavailable = await Flight.findOneAndUpdate(
    { flightName: flight },
    {
      $set: { "sits.$[s].isAvailable": false, "sits.$[s].isSuspended": false },
    },
    { arrayFilters: [{ "sits.sitNumber": sit }], new: true }
  );

  return res.send(sitUnavailable);
};
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Where and how is `startTimer` called?

Comment: do  you get any messages in the console when clicking the button? Your timer component has nothing to do with the problem, not a single thread issue, unless of course you can proof by removing timer component and then it works...